# Use query return results as DB names, add schema and table, then use them in another query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a catalog DB that stores the names of other DBs. These DBs contains the same schema and tabls. Now I want to extract all the DB names from the catalog DB and query a specific table in all those DBs.

Here is an example:

```
catalog DB name: CatalogDB 
schema name: schemaExp
table name: tableExp
CatalogDB contains a list of otherDBs, e.g., otherDB1, otherDB2, otherDBXYZ, etc.
```

So I can get all the other DB names by

```
select DBName
from CatalogDB;
```

I can query the table in otherDB1 using the following query

```
select *
from otherDB1.schemaExp.tableExp;
```

I want to query the same tableExp in all the other DBs. How can I do that?

EDIT: I am not interested in combining tables since table content can get updated. Is it possible to query the catalog db and put the return db names in a parameter then run a query to select from each DBs from the parameter?

Comment: How big is the list of DBs? Does the list keep growing, or is it more or less static?

Comment: size is likely not a concern. The list can change over time. @PhilCoulson

Comment: Are you not looking to do it via SQL script/anonymous block? If not, you can just fetch all DB names in a cursor and loop thru that - prefixing DB name in main select query execute immediate 'select column-list from '||:dbnamevar_from_cursor||' .schema_name.table_name'

Answer (score 1):

So if you wanted to select row count for "all those tables" you could:

```
create table test.test.cat_tab(cat_db string, cat_schema string, cat_table string, other_dbs array);

create database test_a;
create schema test_a.test;
create table test_a.test.table_exp(val int);
insert into test_a.test.table_exp values (1),(2);

create database test_b;
create schema test_b.test;
create table test_b.test.table_exp(val int);
insert into test_b.test.table_exp values (3);

insert into test.test.cat_tab select 'test', 'test', 'table_exp', array_construct('test_a','test_b');
```

then dynamically count those great data driven rows:

```
declare
  counts int;
  total_counts int := 0; 
begin
 let c1 cursor for select f.value::text ||'.'|| cat_schema ||'.'|| cat_table as fqn from test.test.cat_tab,table(flatten(input=>other_dbs)) f where cat_table = 'table_exp';
  for record in c1 do
    let str := 'select count(*) from ' || record.fqn;
    execute immediate str;
    
    select $1 into counts from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
    total_counts := total_counts + counts;
  end for;
  return total_counts;
end;
```

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| 3 |

if you want to select from all those tables in a union greatness:

```
declare
  sql string := '';
  res resultset;
begin
 let c1 cursor for select f.value::text ||'.'|| cat_schema ||'.'|| cat_table as fqn from test.test.cat_tab,table(flatten(input=>other_dbs)) f where cat_table = 'table_exp';
  for record in c1 do
    if (sql <> '') then 
        sql := sql || ' union all '; 
    end if;
    
    sql := sql || 'select * from ' || record.fqn;
  end for;
  
  res := (execute immediate :sql);
  return table(res);
end;
```

gives:

| VAL |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Comment: i got the approach, but how do i get the DB names into that array_construct? The example is doing it manually. But I have to get it from a DB.

Comment: also table() does not seem supported

Comment: @drdot you state first word of the question `I have a catalog DB that stores the names of other DBs` so your question `how do i get the DB names into that array_construct` seems counter point to this statement. Do you have the names or not. If you don't have them, don't say you have them.

Comment: yes, I have it...but how do i get it into the array_construct? Sorry if the question sounds noob...I actually get it working by store procedure with JS. But I would like to learn this way as well.

Comment: To be more specific, your example uses `insert into test.test.cat_tab select 'test', 'test', 'table_exp', array_construct('test_a','test_b');` test_a and test_b are DB names. How would you read the DBname database and put the DB names in the array_construct? The example looks like manually putting it one by one to me.

Comment: you can use ARRAY_AGG to collect table names if you are select from some other table that has table per row, like a system information table. To build the tables. But it's getting a little chicken and egg, if you have sql that builds an array of table names, you don't need sql that unpacks the array, it could just run the original sql and run a line per answer row. But there are many paths to a working solution.

Comment: Ok, if you can just update the post with one way you think is good so the solution works more or less end to end. Happy to take it as an answer.