# Perform Snowflake SQL queries in FOR LOOP based on data from another table

Tags: sql, for-loop, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I am trying to create a SQL script with a for loop that outputs the results into a new table based on the the data_type column

I have a table called PROFILE_TABLE_LIST that has the columns with a
table name and column name, and data type as shown below:

| TABLENAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Table1 | PLANTS | TEXT |
| Table1 | HEIGHT | FLOAT |
| Table2 | COLOR | TEXT |
| Table2 | SMELL | TEXT |

I am currently trying to do a for loop using a cursor and perform the queries on each of the rows to profile the table based on the column types to look something like this:

| TABLENAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | COUNT | MAX_LENGTH | MAX_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table1 | PLANTS | TEXT | 10 | 82 | NULL |
| Table1 | HEIGHT | FLOAT | 10 | NULL | 58.6 |
| Table2 | COLOR | TEXT | 20 | 56 | NULL |
| Table2 | SMELL | TEXT | 20 | 23 | NULL |

Eventually, I want to run different select statements conditioned on the data_type, but at this stage, I am only focusing on the count. This is the current loop I have. However, the select statement is not getting executed properly as the table name is being passed as a string, and if I use TABLE(tablename) I receive a syntax error (I have that line commented out below:

```
declare
    tablename string;
    column_name string;
    row_count integer;
    table_schema string;
    table_catalog string;
    name string;
    
    tmp_array ARRAY default ARRAY_CONSTRUCT();

    res resultset default (select * from PROFILE_TABLE_LIST);
    c1 cursor for res;
    rs_output RESULTSET;
begin

  for record in c1 do
    tablename := record.TABLENAME;
    column_name := record.column_name;
    table_schema := record.table_schema;
    table_catalog := record.table_catalog;
   
   
    
    tmp_array := array_append(:tmp_array, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('tmp_tables', record.TABLENAME, 'COUNT', (SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM tablename)));
    -- tmp_array := array_append(:tmp_array, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('tmp_tables', record.TABLENAME, 'COUNT', (SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM TABLE(tablename))));
 
     
    
  end for;

  rs_output := (select value:tmp_tables, value:COUNT from table(flatten(:tmp_array)));
  return table(rs_output);
end;
```

Comment: something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71669922/use-query-return-results-as-db-names-add-schema-and-table-then-use-them-in-ano/71673920#71673920

Comment: or the same thing, but different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549976/snowflake-data-unloading-multiple-tables/71552286#71552286

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @SimeonPilgrim, these tasks are very similar, but I'm struggling with the syntax. Do you have any advice on how to make the SELECT statement work from within the for loop using the tablenames extracted from the other table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would build a block of SQL and run it at the end.

Which initialing using a simple SELECT as a pattern to show the building up process, that you could write your own dynamic sql from:

```
WITH table_list as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('Table1', 'PLANTS', 'TEXT'),
    ('Table1', 'HEIGHT', 'FLOAT'),
    ('Table2', 'COLOR', 'TEXT'),
    ('Table2', 'SMELL', 'TEXT')
    v(tablename, column_name, data_type)
), to_rows as (
    SELECT
        tablename
        ,CASE data_type
            WHEN 'TEXT' THEN 'SELECT ''tablename'' as TABLENAME, ''column_name'' as COLUMN_NAME, ''data_type'' as DATA_TYPE, count(column_name) as count, MAX(LEN(column_name)) as max_length, null as max_value FROM tablename '
            WHEN 'FLOAT' THEN 'SELECT ''tablename'' as TABLENAME, ''column_name'' as COLUMN_NAME, ''data_type'' as DATA_TYPE, count(column_name) as count, null as max_length, MAX(column_name) as max_value FROM tablename '
        END as sql
        ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(sql, 'data_type', data_type), 'column_name', column_name), 'tablename', tablename) as final_sql
    FROM table_list
)
SELECT
    listagg (final_sql, ' UNION ALL ') within group(order by tablename) as the_big_sql
FROM to_rows;
```

which gives:

| THE_BIG_SQL |
| --- |
| SELECT 'Table1' as TABLENAME, 'PLANTS' as COLUMN_NAME, 'TEXT' as DATA_TYPE, count(PLANTS) as count, MAX(LEN(PLANTS)) as max_length, null as max_value FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT 'Table1' as TABLENAME, 'HEIGHT' as COLUMN_NAME, 'FLOAT' as DATA_TYPE, count(HEIGHT) as count, null as max_length, MAX(HEIGHT) as max_value FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT 'Table2' as TABLENAME, 'COLOR' as COLUMN_NAME, 'TEXT' as DATA_TYPE, count(COLOR) as count, MAX(LEN(COLOR)) as max_length, null as max_value FROM Table2 UNION ALL SELECT 'Table2' as TABLENAME, 'SMELL' as COLUMN_NAME, 'TEXT' as DATA_TYPE, count(SMELL) as count, MAX(LEN(SMELL)) as max_length, null as max_value FROM Table2 |

Which if ran against these tables:

```
create table table1(plants text, height float);
create table table2(color text, smell text);

insert into table1 values ('big plant', 10.1),('medium plant', 5.3),('tiny', 1.0);
insert into table2 values ('red', 'bold'), ('blue', 'weak');
```

gives:

| TABLENAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | COUNT | MAX_LENGTH | MAX_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table1 | PLANTS | TEXT | 3 | 12 |  |
| Table1 | HEIGHT | FLOAT | 3 |  | 10.1 |
| Table2 | COLOR | TEXT | 2 | 4 |  |
| Table2 | SMELL | TEXT | 2 | 4 |  |

But here is the dynamic answer fully written for you:

first making the TABLE with the work to be done:

```
CREATE TABLE PROFILE_TABLE_LIST AS 
SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('Table1', 'PLANTS', 'TEXT'),
    ('Table1', 'HEIGHT', 'FLOAT'),
    ('Table2', 'COLOR', 'TEXT'),
    ('Table2', 'SMELL', 'TEXT')
    v(tablename, column_name, data_type);
```

and using the prior created "real data tables" we can use:

```
declare
    sql string;
    final_sql string;
    c1 cursor for (select * from PROFILE_TABLE_LIST);
    res resultset;
begin
  final_sql := '';
  
  for record in c1 do
    if(record.data_type = 'TEXT') THEN
        sql := 'SELECT '''||record.tablename||''' as TABLENAME, '''||record.column_name||''' as COLUMN_NAME, '''||record.data_type||''' as DATA_TYPE, count('||record.column_name||') as count, MAX(LEN('||record.column_name||')) as max_length, null as max_value FROM '||record.tablename||' ';
    else
        sql := 'SELECT '''||record.tablename||''' as TABLENAME, '''||record.column_name||''' as COLUMN_NAME, ''data_type'' as DATA_TYPE, count('||record.column_name||') as count, null as max_length, MAX('||record.column_name||') as max_value FROM '||record.tablename||' ';
    end if;
    if(final_sql<>'')then 
        final_sql := final_sql || ' UNION ALL ';
    end if;
    final_sql := final_sql || sql;
        
  end for;

  res := (execute immediate :final_sql);
  return table(res);
end;
```

gives:

| TABLENAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | COUNT | MAX_LENGTH | MAX_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table1 | PLANTS | TEXT | 3 | 12 |  |
| Table1 | HEIGHT | data_type | 3 |  | 10.1 |
| Table2 | COLOR | TEXT | 2 | 4 |  |
| Table2 | SMELL | TEXT | 2 | 4 |  |

Comment: This is by far a better solution than I originally proposed and also solves syntax riddle of naming tables.

Comment: This code gives an <EOF> error in the "Classic Console" environment of Snowflake. It does work in the new console though.

Comment: @Eren, this is a known "Classic Console" does not allow naked declare blocks, and thus needs to be wrapped in `$$` but people using the Classic console have had an account for over a year, and will be getting pestered to upgrade, thus should "known" the cost of the old system they are on.